# odoo12 how to show success message without break

Tags: odoo-12

everybody, please help

in odoo, i know that the error message showing was use raise UserError(), but this function will break the function and rollback in database, what i want to do is just simplely show the successful message to user without break, like operation was successful!.

of course, i have try to use the wizard, but the footer is not working, the page always show the save and discard

appreciate if anybody can help me on this. 
thanks.

Comment: If you need to hide Save and Discard buttons add an empty footer to the form.

Comment: thanks,i have found the reason why the footer is not working, because of my fault,i had put the wizard xml file in Views folder, now i am knowing it's should be saved in the wizard folder.thanks anyway kenly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that, you can use the `onchange` API to work around this,

```
@api.onchange('my_field')
def my_field_change(self):
    // warning message
    return {
        'warning': {'title': _('Error'), 'message': _('Error message'),},
     }
```

With that, Perform the change with your case `return` the warning message and it does not break the process.You can find a similar behavior on Odoo **Sale** App on **sale order line product change** operation.

Thanks

Comment: thanks Dipen, i have used the code "self.env.cr.commit()" before raise or return function, it's also working,thanks again.